# Why do JUnit 5 Suite annotations @SelectClasses and @IncludeClassNamePatterns fail to find tests that don't end in "Tests" or "Test"?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

While upgrading to JUnit 5 (version 5.5.2), I have made a strange discovery with the suite functionality: my suites can find and run tests that end with the word "Test" but fail to find tests that don't end in "Test" (in my case, they end in "Base").

In JUnit 4, we used the `@Suite.SuiteClasses()` annotation to find these tests, but the JUnit 5 `@SelectClasses` annotation seems to miss these test classes entirely. Even using `@IncludeClassNamePatterns({"^Com.*Base.*?$"})` fails to detect the tests, which I found strange (the tests I want to run start with "Com"). After this, I tried the `@Tag()` annotation, which didn't work either.

I assumed this was because Maven Surefire (version 2.22.2) only detects test classes that start with Test, or end with Test, Tests, or TestCase. So, I tried to include my Base test case:

```
<includes>
        <include>**/*Base.java</include>
        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
        <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Maven was able to run these Base tests when I built this project, but the test suites still failed to find them.

My code will look similar to the following:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({
    Com_TestOne_Base.class,
    Com_TestTwo_Base.class,
    Com_TestThree_Base.class,
    Com_TestFour_Base.class,
    Com_TestFive_Base.class,
    Com_TestSix_Base.class,
})
public class Com_Base_Suite {
}
```

The result of running this suite is a success, but no tests actually run. All these tests have been updated to JUnit 5 and run successfully on their own.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're running into results from mixing up JUnit 4 and 5. Maven Surefire is able to run JUnit 5 (aka JUnit platform) tests out of the box - given you have the right dependencies in your pom. See e.g. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven for a minimal pom.xml.

`JUnitPlatform`, `SelectClasses` et al. allow you to run JUnit platform tests through JUnit 4. You'd probably only want to do that if your build tool or IDE do not support the JUnit platform themselves. JUnit 5 does currently not have any explicit support for test suites similar to JUnit 4's `@Suite` annotation.

I recommend you get rid of `Com_Base_Suite` alltogether and go with a naming convention that can be configured through Maven's `<includes>` section.

Comment: I believe I am forced to use the JUnitPlaform, as according to the user guide:

`@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SuiteDisplayName("JUnit Platform Suite Demo")
@SelectPackages("example")
public class JUnitPlatformSuiteDemo {
}`

Additionally, it states:
_By default, it will only include test classes whose names either begin with Test or end with Test or Tests._

So, I would assume that @IncludeClassNamePatterns() would add to (or replace) the current patterns it searches for. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Forced by what? If you really want to go that route you’ll probably run into problems with the dependencies since you’ll need all the Junit5 dependencies but also make sure that Surefire won’t run JUnit 5 tests by itself. A lot of idiosyncratic configuration necessary for what purpose? Most, if not all, of what you can do with RunWith(JUnitPlatform) can also be achieved with standard Maven means.

Comment: [Section 4.4.4](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite) of the user guide states that is the correct way to format suites. Additionally, if @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) is deleted, Eclipse will not detect this as a JUnit class, and I cannot run the test suite (which is the reason I am forced to use RunWith). If I run this suite as JUnit 4, the tests run by the suite will run on the vintage engine, so my JUnit 5 tests will still execute. These suites are really just for my convenience so I can run groups of tests together.

Comment: Eclipse has had JUnit 5 support for quite a while so you might want to install a newer version and get rid of those problems. If you can't upgrade you probably have to include suffix "_Suite" in your Maven config otherwise the suite will not be picked up - I assume.